# Heartbeat for autoscaled service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, heartbeat, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm publishing custom metrics to cloudwatch as the heartbeat and I want to set an alarm to check for it every 1 hour. But how can I verify that I got the metrics from all the running instances(autoscaled).

Example: If I get 2 metrics in the last 1 hour but what if I have 3 server instance running how can I catch this case with cloudwatch alarms